# Vector space function question

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-fields

Q:
Let $X$ be a set and $\Bbb F$ be a field. Consider the vector space $V=Fun(X,\Bbb F)$ of functions from $X$ to $\Bbb F$ with operations of addition and mult.
(i) Describe the zero element of V and show that it holds the condition of axiom vs3 (which is the existence of zero in vector space).
(ii) for each function f in V, describe the additive inverse -f and show that it satisfies the conditions of axiom vs4 ( which is the existence of an inverse vector)

---

I am unsure how to do both parts but this is what I have. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

For i) I put if V has the operations of addition and mult then let there be f,-f in V and then (f+(-f))(x)=f(x)+(-f(x))=0 which is an element of V. So the axiom vs3 holds since there exists a 0 in V.

For ii) I have no idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer for i) is a valid answer for (ii).  For (i), it is enough to state that $f(x) = 0$ gives you the zero-vector.

Answer (score 0):

To describe a function, you must define its value $f(x)$ for any $x$. 
Since $\mathbb F$ is a Field, it has a zero, which is the neutral element of the sum of $\mathbb F$. So, you can define the zero function
$$z(x)=0 \ \ \forall x\in X$$

Clearly $z$ is the neutral element of the sum of $V$ as
$$(f+z)(x)=f(x)+z(x)=f(x)+0=f(x)\qquad \forall x\in X$$

For $-f$ you need to find a function such that
$$(-f+f)=z\qquad i.e. \qquad (-f+f)(x)=z(x)\ \  \forall x\in X$$

Since $\mathbb F$ is field, any element has an additive inverse. 
Thus, for any $f\in V$ you can define
$$g_f(x)=-f(x)$$

Now you have $$(g_f+f)(x)=-f(x)+f(x)=0=z(x)\qquad \forall x\in X$$
Therefore $g_f=-f$ as elements of $V$.

Note that you can do all the above because of the properties of $\mathbb F$. If you try replace $\mathbb F$ with $\mathbb N$...

Comment: For i), our teacher said that we also have to show that (f+g)(x) and f(x) are equal functions.       for them to be equal they have to have the same domain, codomain and same rule which assigns each element from dom to codomain right?. How do I show this?

Comment: thas is exactly shown in the second formula you reed in the answer